# How i can change the text of the next span

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have the following markup inside my sharepoint web page (which i can not have control over the markup):-

```
<span dir="none">
<select id="OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice" title="Assign To Approver Required Field" class="ms-RadioText">
<option value="f**">f**</option>
<option value="m**">m**</option>
<option value="m**">m**</option>
<option value="t**">t**</option>
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</span>
<br>
<span class="ms-metadata">AddSourceHere</span>
```

now i am trying to find a way using javascript or jquery, to dynamically change the text of the span which comes after the select list from "AddSourceHere" to something else.

what i am trying to do:-

1. select the select list which have specific id
2. select the next span
3. change the span text.

Comment: Please add you code too

Comment: I take it the "something else" has to do with the `select`?

Comment: `$('.ms-metadata').text('something else')`

Comment: @DanielBeck but there are many element whichnhave `.ms-metadata` class

Comment: OK, that would've been worth mentioning in the question.  Can you trust the ID on the `<select>` to not change?

Comment: `$('select.ms-RadioText').next('span.ms-metadata').text('testing')`?

Comment: If none of the solutions here work for you perhaps you could reword your question to be more specific and/or include more of the context? As it is there are many ways to achieve this kind of thing and it's not clear what will work based on what you have shown us.

Comment: @ChrisM yes correct i edited my question with more detials

Comment: @DanielBeck sorry for not clearing this from the beginning, yes the id for the select list is trusted and unique

Comment: @johnG I have updated my answer with an edit to match your updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just find the dropdown by id and use `nextAll` to find the span.

```js
$('#OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_\\$DropDownChoice')
            .parent('span')
            .nextAll('span.ms-metadata:eq(0)')                
            .text("Some new value");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span dir="none">
  <select id="OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice" title="Assign To Approver Required Field" class="ms-RadioText">
    <option value="f**">f**</option>
    <option value="m**">m**</option>
    <option value="m**">m**</option>
    <option value="t**">t**</option>
  <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</span>
<br>
<span class="ms-metadata">AddSourceHere</span>
```

Note the one sticky point is that you have a `$` in your select id, which needs to be escaped when using as a selector in jQuery.

---

You can also do this with straight javascript, but its a bit nasty.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice');

select.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML = "Some text here"
```

```html
<span dir="none">
  <select id="OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice" title="Assign To Approver Required Field" class="ms-RadioText">
    <option value="f**">f**</option>
    <option value="m**">m**</option>
    <option value="m**">m**</option>
    <option value="t**">t**</option>
  <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</span>
<br>
<span class="ms-metadata">AddSourceHere</span>
```

Comment: i do not need to updated based on the select list value

Comment: now the markup you mentioned is not 100% compatible with the markup i showed.. as there are a parent span

Comment: @DanielBeck yes correct the code was not pasted correctly from my side

Comment: Sigh. yes that changed since you first posted as well.

Comment: yes it was my fault , i copied the code directly from firefox F12 ,, not sure why it sxip it

Answer (score 2):

You've indicated in comments that the ID on the select element can be trusted, but that there are other `.ms-metadata` elements that shouldn't be changed, so we can't depend solely on that class.

<strike>Three</strike> Four parts of this to watch out for:

- Your ID includes a `$`, which needs to be escaped in a jQuery selector (as `\\$`)
- The elements aren't siblings, so `next()` won't work to traverse from the `<select>` to the `<span>`. Instead use `nextAll()`
- Prevent that nextAll from spilling into all the following spans using `eq:(0)` or `first()`
- You've changed the HTML structure, so throw in a `.parent()` to compensate

An example in action:

```js
$("#OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_\\$DropDownChoice")      // the select element
  .parent()                           // climb up to the parent span
  .nextAll('span.ms-metadata:eq(0)')  // get the first following .ms-metadata
  .text('This text was changed')      // change the text
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span dir="none">
  <select id="OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice" title="Assign To Approver Required Field" class="ms-RadioText">
    <option value="f**">f**</option>
    <!-- other options omitted for brevity -->
  </select>
</span>
<br>
<span class="ms-metadata">AddSourceHere</span>
<span class="ms-metadata">This should not be affected</span>
```

Comment: now the markup you mentioned is not 100% compatible with the markup i showed.. as there are a parent span..can you check my original code again..thanks

Comment: That span wasn't in the question when I wrote this answer; you edited it in after the fact.

Comment: yes i wrongly added the code to the question.. so i edited with the correct markup

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one span with the class ms-metadata and/or you are only concerned with the first span with that class...

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ms-metadata')[0].innerHTML = 'something else';
```

jQuery:

```
$('.ms-metadata').first().text('something else');
```

Comment: but i do not want to based the selection on the `ms-metadata`i want to base it on the select list id which i can guarantee that it is unique

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to find a way using javascript or jquery, to dynamically change the text of the span which comes after the select list

If your title text is unique in nature

```
$("select[title='Assign To Approver Required Field']").nextAll('span').text('whatever you like')
```

Comment: i tried your appraoch but the text for the span was not updated...i also checked the console and i find that there is not any error

Comment: I have updated,I failed to notice there was a br tag in between so you have to use nextAll.

Comment: this also did not change the text for the span!!

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can do this depending on how you want to structure your code and what dependencies you are willing to accept. Using jQuery:

**Dependent on the class of the span**

```
 $('.ms-metadata').text('something else')
```

**Dependent on following the select**

```
$('select.ms-radioText').nextAll('span').text('something else')
```

You could even combine these two like this to be more specific:

```
$('select.ms-radioText').sibling('.ms-metadata').text('something else')
```

These are just examples based on what you have shown us. There are other ways but which is appropriate will depend on the rest of your code.

**Edit:**

Based on your updated question this is the most direct way to do what you need, again using jQuery. Assign your text to variable `newText` (note that the `$` character [has to be escaped](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) with two forward slashes like this `\\$`).

```
 var selectID = "OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_\\$DropDownChoice";
 var newText = "something else";
 $("#"+selectID).nextAll('span:eq(0)').text(newText);
```

Comment: this will raise the following exception `exception= Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice`

Comment: The issue was the '$' in the ID. You can resolve this by escaping it with two forward slashes. I have updated the answer to reflect this.